# Использование hibernate несколькими приложениями

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Сложилась такая ситуация, есть несколько отдельных приложений, которые используют одну базу данных. Конкретнее, есть приложение на vaadin'e и есть сервер на spring boot для мобильного приложения. У каждого из этих приложений есть в зависимостях модуль hibernate, который работает c одной БД. Выходит так, что при запуске этих приложений получается два объекта SessionFactory, в результате чего при внесении изменений в БД через одно приложение, другое приложение не видит изменения пока не почистить кэш hibernate. Справляемся сейчас таким способом, практически не используем кэш, но приложения становятся все больше, запросы сложнее и т.д и т.п.

И теперь вопрос. Как можно выйти из сложившейся ситуации? Как использовать hibernate с включенным кешем?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509/2393786

Comment: Выйти из сложившейся ситуации можно пересмотрев архитектуру и способы взаимодействия приложений.